# Time derivative of Local time

Tags: analysis, stochastic-analysis, local-time

Consider a Ito Process,not necessarily Brownian Motion, $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ starting at 0 and define the associated Local Time at $0$:

\begin{equation}
L_{t}=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{1}_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}(X_{s})ds.
\end{equation}

I want to show that **$L_{t}$ is not differentiable at $0$**. I suspect that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{1}_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}(X_{s})ds
\end{equation}
this limit is not well defined.

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\mathbb{1}_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}(X_{s})ds
\end{equation}
is clearly not well defined but I cannot quite justify the switching of limits. Is this the right approach in regards to answering this problem?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find an answer to that question?